# HTTPS with gunicorn?

Tags: https, gunicorn

I am running Gunicorn 19.0 on a Debian server to serve a Django 1.8 site. I am also running nginx to serve the site's static assets.

My DNS is managed by Gandi and I have CloudFlare in front of the server. The site is running happily on HTTP. Now I would like to serve it over HTTPS. My question is about how to go about this.

I have generated a certificate by [following Gandi's instructions](http://wiki.gandi.net/en/ssl/csr). Now I have a `server.csr` and a `myserver.key` file on my server.

I have a script to run Gunicorn and I have amended it to point at these certificate files:

```
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
   --certfile=/home/me/server.csr
   --keyfile=/home/me/myserver.key
   --name $NAME \
   --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
   --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
   --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
   --log-level=debug \
   --log-file=-
```

The script seems to run cleanly as usual, but now if I go to https://example.com or http://example.com there is nothing there (521 and 404 respectively).

Is there an additional step I need to carry out?

The Gunicorn logs show the following:

```
Starting myapp as hello
[2015-06-25 10:28:18 +0000] [11331] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-06-25 10:28:18 +0000] [11331] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
[2015-06-25 10:28:18 +0000] [11331] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-06-25 10:28:19 +0000] [11331] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
[2015-06-25 10:28:19 +0000] [11331] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-06-25 10:28:20 +0000] [11331] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
[2015-06-25 10:28:20 +0000] [11331] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-06-25 10:28:21 +0000] [11331] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
[2015-06-25 10:28:21 +0000] [11331] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-06-25 10:28:22 +0000] [11331] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
[2015-06-25 10:28:22 +0000] [11331] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-06-25 10:28:23 +0000] [11331] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 8000)
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US)
```

I'm also confused because most of the gunicorn examples talk about `.crt` files, but I only have a `.csr` file.

Comment: I am running NGINX/Unicorn/Rails, so it may not be totally analogous, but I think SSL should be set up in your NGINX config, not your Gunicorn one.  When you set up NGINX, you'll need to decide if you want to serve both plain text and SSL or redirect everything to SSL.

Comment: CSR is certificate signing request - submit it somewhere to get a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

What @SteveKlein says above in the comments:

```
SSL should be set up in your NGINX config, not your Gunicorn one. 
When you set up NGINX, you'll need to decide if you want to serve 
both plain text and SSL or redirect everything to SSL.
```